# NGRX - how to have calculated properties on items in the store

Tags: angular, ngrx

We're using NGRX in our Angular applications. Data is coming from an API. Certain properties come from the API as an unformatted string, so we need to format this. Of course this can be done in the HTML, but the problem is that the value is required in multiple locations, in both HTML as well as in TypeScript.

So, initially we created getters for these display properties on our domain objects, but it is not supported by ngrx to store complex objects in the store as they are not serializable. ngrx should store simple JavaScript interfaces.

I don't know what the proper solution is, some options I had in mind:
- In the reducer, when the entities are updated/added, populate the display properties.
- In the selector, when the entities are retrieved, enrich them with the display properties.
- Have effects that is triggered every time an entity is updated/added to enrich them with the display properties.

Every solution requires that the reducer/selector/effect transforms / enriches the input by calling a function. If that's forgotten, the display data is outdated/missing.
It just does not feel right.

Any other suggestions please?

Comment: selectors should map the basic domain objects into class instances with getters for the calculated properties. Ideally, those classes would have static factory methods like `FooClass.fromModel(obj: FooModel)`. IMO would be better than storing models with calculated data which can be inferred from their other properties.

Comment: _If that's forgotten, the display data is outdated/missing. It just does not feel right._ this is a complex issue indeed. Theoretically, one could create proxy classes on the fly of the domain model classes which are bounded to the store. Whenever a property in an instance of the proxy class is changed, the store is updated, problem being _how_ do you notify the store what action is to be done. TBH I feel like the complexity that this adds isnt worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks @Jota.Toledo much appreciated. 

I like the selector approach. Think we need to split up our domain into Contracts/DTO, and Models. 
Contracts would mimic what's in the API, and also what's stored in the store. They will be interfaces
Models would be returned by selector, they are classes with the getter properties.

Are there any gaps with this approach?

Comment: Other than the overhead caused by having 2 objects for every domain model entry, I cant think of any large disadvantages of the approach.

Comment: Yeah think that's the only approach. Investigating! :) Thanks @Jota.Toledo

Comment: Take a look at the following link, the author explains how Doman Driven Design techniques still apply for your client applications but how they can take a more functional approach because of the nature of the language (javascript/typescript) https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/tactical-domain-driven-design-with-monorepos/